# Parsing a CSV into 2D array generates NullPointerException

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, methods

Using ReadInputCSVFromFile method to read the sample CSV from file and parse it to a String array after using split(",") function and pass it to a 2D array to read it fully.
PrintResultsForTesting method would be only for printing out the 2D array for visual overlook.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSVReader {
    public static String[][] readIntoArray;
    public static String[][] myArray;
    public static String[][] csvResults;
    public static int countRow = 0;
    public static int countColumn = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        csvResults = ReadInputCSVFromFile(myArray);
        PrintResultsForTesting(csvResults);
    }

    public static void PrintResultsForTesting(String[][] csvResults) {
        String[][] newMyArray = new String[myArray.length][myArray[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < csvResults.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < csvResults[0].length; ++j) {
                System.out.println(csvResults[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String[][] ReadInputCSVFromFile(String[][] myArray) {
        countRow = 0;
        countColumn = 0;
        Scanner scanner;
        String inputLine;
        String fileLocation;

        fileLocation = "D://WorkSpace_Git//methods//iq-distribution//docs/SAP.csv";
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation)));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] readIntoArray = inputLine.split(",");

                // count rows and columns
                ++countRow;
                countColumn = readIntoArray.length;
                myArray = new String[countRow][countColumn];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < countRow; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < countColumn; ++j) {
                    myArray[i][j] = readIntoArray[i][j];

                }
            }
            System.out.println("Rows: " + countRow + '\n' + "Columns: " + countColumn);
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at project.CSVReader.ReadInputCSVFromFile(CSVReader.java:52) at project.CSVReader.main(CSVReader.java:16) Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Whats the issue? Are you getting error messages? What are you stuck on?

Comment: ok so the error is the following:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at project.CSVReader.ReadInputCSVFromFile(CSVReader.java:52)
 at project.CSVReader.main(CSVReader.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking briefly at your code, I could spot a bug. When this method is called:

```
public static String[][] ReadInputCSVFromFile(String[][] myArray) {
```

`myArray` is `null`.

If you want to write to the array, you will need to instantiate the array first.

If you are using arrays actually you should know in advance its dimensions. If you do not know it, consider using some implementation of `java.util.List` - like `java.util.ArrayList`.

Another problem is exception handling. If the file is not found, then the exception is caught and you still call this method `PrintResultsForTesting` with unpredicatable results. Better to use a `throws` clause and stop the execution alltogether. So instead of the `try` `catch` in method `ReadInputCSVFromFile` just use a `throws FileNotFoundException` in this method.